# Is there a way to recover a closed terminal used to open and interact with omxplayer?

Tags: ssh, terminal, omxplayer

omxplayer runs on raspberry pi from a terminal.  I am opening it and controlling it from my Ubuntu via SSH.  If I force close the SSH terminal and reboot my Ubuntu the raspberry pi continues to play the video but I can no longer control it as I closed the terminal.  Can I somehow recover the terminal used to open omxplayer so that I can control it again?